# Card counting with 2 decks

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Assume you have 104 cards between two decks and the cards are distinct only by suit and value. After being dealt two cards, how many distinct pairs can you be dealt ? If you have 10, J, Q, K, A as winning cards - how many winning cards can you get? Order is irrelevant.

Comment: This needs clarification: are you dealt one card from each deck or are both decks shuffled together before dealing two cards ? Does Ace of Spade & Ace of Spade counts as a pair ? "how many winning cards can you get?" is also a weird question, if you're deal two cards you can get a maximum of two winning cards. Are you loooking for the probability of being dealt at least one wining card ? Or the expected value of the number of winning cards dealt ?

Comment: They're standard decks. You don't know which deck the cards come from. The "distinct" pairs should lead towards being unique. This is mostly looking at the number of ways you can get them. The "winning" cards, I think, leads towards 40 total winning cards (4 of each across suits from each deck?)

Comment: By 'pair of cards', you mean a 2-set of cards, any hand made of two cards, right ? Not what a poker-player would call a pair, i.e. 7-7 or Q-Q ?

Comment: Note that two Aces of Clubs is half as likely as an Ace of Heats plus an Ace of Diamonds

Comment: I think distinct pairs means what you are referring too. i.e. 7-7 etc

Answer (score 1):

- *How many distinct pairs can you be dealt ?*

**If it means number of distinct 2-sets of cards**

Pairs of two identical cards : $52$

Pairs of two different cards: $\binom{52}{2}=26*51=1326$

Total : you can receive $1326+52=1378$ different 2-sets of cards.

**If it means number of distinct hands made of two cards of the same height**

For each height, there are $\binom{4}{2}=6$ possible pairs with different suits and $4$ pairs with twice the same suit, hence $10$ possible pairs.

So the number of distinct hands made of two cards of the same height is $13*10=130$

- *how many winning cards can you get?*

2 at most, since you're dealt two cards and both of them can be a winning card.

Comment: I think winning cards is referring to - of the 104 cards, you can receive 40 winning cards so how many pairs would this be or (52 20) ?

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you mean, do we have to calculate how many different hands made of two winning cards we can get ?

Comment: Or how many different hands with at least one winning card ?

Comment: How many pairs of winning cards i.e. if you are dealt 2 - how many winning cards can you get ?

Comment: So I think how many of the 40 cards that are winning can you get if you got dealt 2 cards ? i.e. (40 2) ?

Comment: Then my answer is correct: you can get 2 winning cards at most. But that doesn't make the question very interesting...